# GLFW not including

Tags: c++, visual-studio, glfw

Hi im using Visual Studio 2022 and Im trying to include GLFW 3 but it says

```
C:\Users\DEV\source\repos\test again\test again\src\main.cpp(1,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLFW/glfw3.h': No such file or directory
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Folders:

[image: Image 4]

[image: Image 5]

[image: Image 6]

Comment: On the last picture is there a Include\GLFW folder containing `glfw3.h`?

Comment: @drescherjm yes

Comment: @drescherjm how do i quote the path?

Comment: Do you compile for Win32 platform or Win64? It seems you set directories only for Win32

Comment: If glfw3.h is in ...\Include\GLFW, you need to change include directories to ...\Include\GLFW.